# Quamotion Spy fails to start on an iPad

Tags: ios, webdriver, certificate

I'm having an issue starting the Remote Control and Spy sessions using the Quamotion WebDriver on an iPad Mini 4 running iOS 10.2.1.

I'm getting the following error message:

> The spy failed to start. The installation of application Quamotion Agent on device iPad failed. The installation proxy returned the error ApplicationVerificationFailed. The following syslog messages may contain more information:
>   0x16df1b000 -[MIClientConnection _doInstallationForURL:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner" type Customer (LSInstallType = (null)) requested by mobile_installation_proxy (pid 203) 0x16df1b000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing  :Install (New):0:Success:Begin could not enable test hierarchy: ApplePinningAllowTestCertsiPhoneApplicationSigning not true [leaf CheckLeafMarkerOid IssuerCommonName Revocation1 SubjectCommonName] could not enable test hierarchy: ApplePinningAllowTestCertsiPhoneApplicationSigning not true [leaf CheckLeafMarkerOid IssuerCommonName Revocation1 SubjectCommonName] [leaf Revocation1] 0x16df1b000 +[MICodeSigningVerifier _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:]: 147: Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.N6uppO/extracted/Payload/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app : 0xe8008018 (The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid.) 0x16df1b000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Verification stage failed :Install (New):0:Fail:End

Are there any steps I can take to troubleshoot this? I can start the Spy and remote control on an iPhone 6.

Answer (score 1):

This most likely indicates that the iOS Developer Certificates you have uploaded in the Quamotion Settings page have been revoked.

You can check the revocations tate of your iOS developer certificate using the following command:

```
openssl ocsp -issuer AppleWWDRCA.pem -cert mycert.pem -text -url http://ocsp.apple.com/ocsp03-wwdr01 -header 'host' 'ocsp.apple.com'
```

You can download the individual certificates in `.cer` format from the Settings page in the Quamotion WebDriver. You can then convert the `.cer` file to `.pem` file using the following OpenSSL command:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in mycert.cer -out mycert.pem
```

You'll also need the Apple WWDR CA certificate, which you can download from https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer .

If your certificate has been revoked, you should get a status message simliar to this:

```
Response Verify Failure
140404648445600:error:27069065:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:certificate 
verify error:ocsp_vfy.c:126:Verify error:self signed certificate in certificate chain
mycert.pem: revoked
        This Update: Mar 14 10:10:08 2018 GMT
        Next Update: Mar 15 10:10:08 2018 GMT
        Reason: keyCompromise
        Revocation Time: Jan 23 08:33:40 2018 GMT
```

Comment: Thanks, one of my certificate has been revoked. I deleted that certificate from the settings page & the Spy now works correctly.